# how to check mysql status on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

My MYSQL installaion has messed up. I tried purging the mysql using

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-client mysql-client-5.0 mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-5.0
```

But it got hanged in middle

I installed again from gui in ubuntu. it get installed

But when i type `service mysql start` using root then system got hanged again , i had to press ctrl C to exit

when i type `telent 127.0.0.1 3306`

it says can't connect.

what should i do

Answer (score 2):

Since you just installed MySQL i can recommend you a few things.

- Make sure the MySQL user and group is present `id mysql` if not, create them `groupadd mysql; useradd mysql -g mysql -M -s /bin/false`
- Make sure the MySQL Data folder user and group are set to mysql user and group `chown -R mysql.mysql /var/lib/mysql` where `/var/lib/mysql` is the path to your MySQL data folder (ie.: /var/lib/mysql is a default place but it may be somewhere else depending on how have you installed it).
- If you don't know where your data directory is, you can check your init mysql script that is inside `/etc/init.d` and look for the entry `--datadir=`
- Before you can run MySQL, you must have a database. To install an initial database, do this as root: [`scripts/mysql_install_db`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-install-db.html)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the mysql daemon don't start up.

Have you tried to check log of mysql in /var/log/mysql ?

for check the status of a daemon in Linux you could type this in your terminal : 
/etc/init.d/mysql status

but seems that your mysql server doesn't start up, therefore the status of the process should be "not running" .

Comment: the status is 
mysql stop/post-start, (post-start) process 699
but when i type service mysql start , then it again got hanged